# RecyclerView не отображает элементы java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.prototype;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView nameView;
    private TextView emailView;
    private TextView telView;
    private TextView commonBalanceView;
    private RecyclerView exchangesListView;
    private User user;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private List<Exchange> exchangeList = new ArrayList<Exchange>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        exchangeList.add(new Exchange("Binance"));
        exchangeList.add(new Exchange("Huobi"));
        exchangeList.add(new Exchange("Coinbase"));
        exchangeList.add(new Exchange("FTX"));
        exchangeList.add(new Exchange("Gemini"));



        nameView = findViewById(R.id.nameView);
        emailView = findViewById(R.id.emailView);
        telView = findViewById(R.id.telView);
        commonBalanceView = findViewById(R.id.commonBalanceView);
        exchangesListView = findViewById(R.id.exchangesListView);
        user = new User("Петров Василий Геннадьевич", "haron4356@mail.ru", "+79345678231");
        nameView.setText(user.getName());
        emailView.setText("EMAIL: " + user.getEmail());
        telView.setText("Телефон: " + user.getTelephone());
        ArrayList<Account>accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

        accounts.add(new Account("5678123", exchangeList.get(2), 4567 ));
        accounts.add(new Account("4567812", exchangeList.get(0), 17687));

        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<accounts.size(); i++)
        {
            sum+= accounts.get(i).getBalance();
        }
        commonBalanceView.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
        adapter = new AccountAdapter(this, accounts);
        exchangesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        commonBalanceView.setText(Integer.toString(exchangesListView.getAdapter().getItemCount()));
        }

     class AccountAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AccountAdapter.ViewHolder>{

        private final LayoutInflater inflater;
        private final List<Account> accounts;

        AccountAdapter(Context context, List<Account> accounts) {
            this.accounts = accounts;
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }
        @Override
        public AccountAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(AccountAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Account account = accounts.get(position);
            holder.UIDView.setText("#" + account.getUID());
            holder.exchangeNameView.setText(account.getExchg().getName());
            holder.balanceView.setText(Integer.toString(account.getBalance()));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return accounts.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView UIDView;
            private TextView exchangeNameView;
            private TextView balanceView;

            ViewHolder(View view){
                super(view);
                exchangeNameView = view.findViewById(R.id.exchangeNameView);
                balanceView = view.findViewById(R.id.balanceView);
                UIDView = view.findViewById(R.id.UIDView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:maxHeight="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exchangeNameView"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="250dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="337dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="337dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:text="Баланс:"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exchangeNameView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/balanceView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="260dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="260dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exchangeNameView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/UIDView"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="89dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="89dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/exchangeNameView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/exchangesListView"
    android:layout_width="408dp"
    android:layout_height="447dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
    tools:listitem="@layout/items"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Конкретизируйте проблему

Comment: Не задан `LayoutManager`, ресайклер не знает как располагать элементы